# Regular expression= tabspace+STRING+tabspace

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I write this as a regular expression?

> tabspaceSTRINGtabspace

My data looks like this:

```
12345   adsadasdasdasd  30
34562   adsadasdasdasd  asdadaads<adasdad   30
12313   adsadasdasdasd  asdadas dsaads  313123<font="TNR">adsada    30
1232131 adsadasdasdasd  asdadaads<adasdad"asdja <div>asdjaıda   30
```

I want to get

```
12345   30
34562   30
12313   30
1232131 30
```

`\t*\t` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try the following regular expression

```
\t.+\t
```

Comment: I'm trying to find&replace all the junk info on a plain text file.

It looks like this: tabspaceTOTALLYRANDOMSTRINGtabspace30

for the find field: \t.+\t30
replace field: \t30

but it doesn't work. I'm using notepad++ and the regular expression option is active. any help?

Comment: I've just added my sample data.

Comment: @MithatCanAyok: If the whitespace in your example are tabs then it works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

What characters are allowed in your string?

```
\t\w+\t
```

`\w` would allow letters, digits and the underscore (depending on your regex engine ASCII or Unicode)

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30lfu), a good platform to test regular expressions.

Your "regex" `\t*\t` would match 0 or more tabs and then one tab. The `*` is a quantifier meaning 0 or more and is referring to the character or group before (here to your `\t`)

If your whitespace are not tabs, try this

```
\s+.+\s+30
```

`\s` is a whitespace character (space, tab, newline (not important for Notepad++)).

Comment: I'm trying to find&replace all the junk info on a plain text file. It looks like this: tabspaceTOTALLYRANDOMSTRINGtabspace30 for the find field: \t.+\t30 replace field: \t30 but it doesn't work. I'm using notepad++ and the regular expression option is active. any help?

Comment: please edit your question if you have additional information. I tried this in my Notepad++ (v5.9.8) and it worked, so not sure where your problem is. Are you sure that those whitespaces are tabs?

Comment: I've just added my sample data.

Comment: The characters in your example are not tabs. I edited my answer, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is your definition of String...

If you use something like the suggested above, it'll match

tabspaceSTRINGtabspacetabspace

You get the picture. This might be acceptable, if not, you need to limit your "STRING" definition, like:

```
\t\w+\t
```

or:

```
\t[a-zA-Z]+\t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the strings you are looking for except that they are separated by tabs it is a good approach to describe such a string as everything but a tab: (^\t*)

```
[^\t]*\t([^\t]*)\t[^\t]*
```

You can test it on [regexpad.com](http://regexpad.com/?r=%5B%5E%5Ct%5D%2a%5Ct%28%5B%5E%5Ct%5D%2a%29%5Ct%5B%5E%5Ct%5D%2a&f=&m0=12345%09adsadasdasdasd%0930#p-javascript).